# Sort arrays in PHP by index

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, indexing

I have following array:

```
   $array[0]["nbr1"] = 5;

   $array[0]["nbr2"] = 7;

   $array[1]["nbr1"] = 1;

   $array[1]["nbr2"] = 6;

   $array[2]["nbr1"] = 2;

   $array[2]["nbr2"] = 3;
```

How can I sort this array first by "nbr1" descending and than by "nbr2" descending? I tried different things that were explained on the web but none of them worked for this scenario.

Thx

Comment: [Canonical reference about sorting arrays in php.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/reference-all-basic-ways-to-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

```
array_multisort($array[1], SORT_DESC, SORT_STRING);
```